# Ubuntu 12.04 using VLANS on Bond0

Tags: network-bonding

I have tried and read just about every article on how to setup VLANs with Bonds, however, I can not seem to get it working.

I am running: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on a IBM x3650M4 with 2 INTEL 10GB NICS.

When I installed the OS, I did not have access to the Internet and I had to mount an ISO with `vlan_1.9-3ubuntu6_amd64.deb` on it to get VLAN support. I ran `modprobe 8021q` and added `8021q` to `/etc/modules`. I am able to configure `eth1` and `eth6` independently to use the vlan (we will call it `vlan1`) and I did update and upgrade Ubuntu as well as aptitude update and upgrade.

My interfaces file looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth6
iface eth6 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# Start bond0
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
      bond-mode 4
      bond-miimon 100
      bond-lacp-rate fast (have tried slow as well)
      mtu 11000
      bond-slaves none

# Start VLAN 1
auto bond0.1
iface bond0.1 inet static
      address 10.1.1.100
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 10.1.1.0
      broadcast 10.1.247.255
      gateway 10.1.1.3
      dns-nameservers 10.1.1.10
vlan-raw-device
```

(the IP info is intentionally wrong)

Whenever I try to bring up `bond0.1` I get this error:

```
Set name-type for VLAN subsystem. Should be visible in /proc/net/vlan/config
ERROR: trying to add VLAN #1 to IF -:bond0:- error: Operation not supported
Cannot find device "bond0.1"
Failed to bring up bond0.1
```

If I run `vconfig add bond0 1`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: trying to add VLAN #1 to IF -:bond0:- error: Operation not supported
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message on Ubuntu 12.04 when I was missing the "ifenslave" package.  I fixed that with this command: `sudo apt-get install ifenslave-2.6`

Comment: Did you do anything with the ifenslave command? Just installing the package didn't solve the problem for me.